# How to negate px from %(percentage)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

How to achieve something like this

```
height: calc(100% - 50px); 
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
```

in non-suppoted browsers?

I have a responsive div, which has two childs. Out of which 1st child's height is in px, and i want the 2nd child should conver remaining spaces of the parent div.
I have achieved it using : calc(), but it wont work with all browser?
JS is my last preference. Ok. Let me have some suggestions please?

Comment: in which browser is it not working?

Comment: See Compatibility table for support of calc() as CSS http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: safari 5< devices does not supports..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a browser that doesn't support the `calc` expression, it's not hard to mimic with jQuery:

```
$('#yourEl').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=50px');
```

if Calc is having problems Let Jquery handle it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If css doesn't work for you, you can get the height of the parent and subtract what you need from it.

```
var parent_height = document.getElementById("parent").offsetHeight; //-- Get Height of an element
document.getElementById("child").style.height = (parent_height - 50) + 'px';
```